# Stored procedure defined by time

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new in programming. Everything went smooth so far, but I can't solve this. I'm using MySQL Workbench 5.2.42

I know I need to create a stored procedure

This procedure needs to delete all data in my database, but only if the data I over 15 minutes old. I can access the time from my timestamp at the `ExpectedEnd` column. But I don't know how to do this right.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_DeleteOldData()
BEGIN
IF ExpectedEnd IS TIMESTAMP + 15 
DELETE * tables FROM (DelayedLoading, Loading, LoadingDock, LoadingError, Orders,     PartOrders, Semi, Trailer, Truck, Weighing)
End ;
```

I made this though its surely completely wrong.

edit*

I tried this, but i still can't figure how to get it to the 15 minute mark and delete.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_DeleteOldData(IN theTime DATETIME)
BEGIN
DELETE FROM Loading WHERE ExpectedEnd < theTime;
END;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to delete all data that is older than 15 minutes or do you mean delete all data if any data is older than 15 minutes?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... things like procedures are **highly** vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: @PHeiberg: I mean if the specific data is older than 15 minutes 

Ok, thanks. I'm using: MySQL Workbench 5.2.42

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_DeleteOldData(IN theTime DATETIME)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Loading WHERE ExpectedEnd < DATE_ADD(theTime, INTERVAL -15 MINUTE);
END;
```

You can see other [interval values in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) (e.g. HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH) and you can even just use NOW() instead of having to pass a time value into the stored procedure if you are only looking at the current point in time